# Reset values in pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a given df with values > 0 and nan.

I want to reset all values > 0 to 1 except the first two columns with:

```
df_sort[df_sort.iloc[:,2] >= 0] = 1
```

Actually this changes my whole df.

I only want reset the values > 0 and keep the nans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask is not correct (the slicing is off and you don't have the full DataFrame shape), you should use:

```
mask = (df_sort.iloc[:, 2:].ge(0)
        .reindex(columns=df_sort.columns,
                 fill_value=False)
       )

df_sort[mask] = 1
```

Alternatively, with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting:

```
mask = df_sort.ge(0).to_numpy() & (np.arange(df_sort.shape[1])>2)[None]
df_sort[mask] = 1
```

Example output:

```
      0     1     2     3     4
0     0  None     1     1  None
1  None  None  None     1  None
2     1     2     1  None     1
3     0     0     1     1     1
4     2  None  None     1     1
```

Example output with `>0` (not `>=0`):

```
      0     1     2     3     4
0     0  None     1     0  None
1  None  None  None     1  None
2     1     2     0  None     1
3     0     0     0     1     1
4     2  None  None     1     0
```

If you want to target values > 0 and only have integers, you could also [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df_sort.update(df_sort.iloc[:, 2:].clip(upper=1))

print(df_sort)
```

Used input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df_sort = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, None], size=(5, 5)))

      0     1     2     3     4
0     0  None     1     0  None
1  None  None  None     1  None
2     1     2     0  None     2
3     0     0     0     2     1
4     2  None  None     2     0
```